# How we can a Send PHP email to gmail archive

Tags: php

How we can a Send a email using PHP mail function to gmail archive mail folder?

My code

```
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Subject" ;
$message = 'Example message with <b>html</b>';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: xxx <xxx>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Note:
Smile email/mail function is fully functional but I want to send mail to  gmail archive folder directly.Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the recipient's e-mail settings, you can't do that on the sender side.